# Comparing two clocks

Tags: special-relativity

My textbook says the following in the context of Special Relativity:

> "If we want to compare two clocks, we have to do that in the same
>   frame of reference and on the same place."

I get it that the frame of reference can't be changed, because time is relative (i.e., dependent on the frame of reference). But what has the position to do with the speed at which the clocks are ticking? Can't we say that the relative velocity should be 0, for us to compare them correctly? Because we could compensate for their relative distance, I'd say, as long as their relative velocity is zero.

Comment: *How* do you propose to compare clocks which are not in the same place?

Comment: Well, you could stand in between the clocks, and make them send you a light signal every time they tick.

Comment: Have a loook at e.g. [Einstein synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation) and the issues with it.

Comment: I'm familiar with Einstein synchronisation. The only issue I know of is that simultaneity (events happening at the same time) becomes relative, i.e., it depends on the observer if two events happen at the same time. You could also say that the duration of events depends on the observer. I still see no problem with measuring the clocks on different locations.

Comment: Could you expand the textbook quote such that we could get a better understanding of what relates to what, etc.

Comment: A translation from my part: "The results in Special Relativity may give rise to paradoxes. From the point of view of observer S we see that in S' the clocks tick slower, but from  the point of view of S' it's the clocks in S that tick slower. Now how is right? Of course they are both right; if we want to compare two clocks, we need to do that in the same reference frame and on the same place."